# How to loop through directories to execute batch and exe files with params from batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a test script to loop through directories recursively and execute a series of steps to automatically upload dynamically created files to my development server. I'm having some trouble with the correct syntax. I hope someone can help me.

I've looked through stack overflow and I've figured out the basic structure of the script.

```
::
:: SUMMARY
:: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: Loops through a series of directories and executes the following steps for each directory
::   1) Execute batch command which runs a SQL query and exports a list of IDs to a file in the
::      Current subdirectory called ids.txt
::   2) Execute an exe that exists in a subdirectory of the directory where the batch file is run
::      that takes the list of IDS and creates CSV files with pre-created test data
:: 
:: TODOS
:: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
::   1) Execute sqlcmd inline instead of calling a seperate batch file
::   2) Execute a process to upload the generated CSV files to DEV server
::   2) Skip any directory that is missing the .sql file or the 
::
:: NOTES
:: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
::   - The process can (and should if possible) be run in parallel for each subdirectory, but the
::     steps for each subdirectory should be run in series
::

@echo off
set back = %cd%
for /R ./ %%i in (.) do (
   cd "%%i"

   call "./RunSql.bat" ids.txt

   :: Run the genreate statements exe in the base folder
   start /WAIT "%back%/CreateStatements/CreateStatements.exe" --background=true --idFile=ids.txt
)
cd %back%
```

I expect the batch file to loop through the directories and run the steps outlined in the comments, but I get the below output for each directory

---

'"./RunSql.bat"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the file --background=true.

Comment: At first, replace the `::`-style comments by `rem` in code blocks since they may lead to unexpected bahaviour...

Comment: 1st if you require `RunSql.bat` to be present in the folder why don't you use it as argument for the `for /r` 2nd while windows accepts the slash instead of the  backslash for pathes, this does not always/everywhere work. 3rd start may take the first argument in double quotes as the window title - insert a (dummy) "title".

Comment: Note that `set back = %cd%` creates variable `%back %` (note trailing space in variable name) and its value contains a leading space. Use `set "back=%cd%"`. Also note that `%CD%` could differ from  the directory where the batch file is run, cf `%~dp0` in [Links relative to the Batch Script](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

Comment: `for /R ./ %%i in (.) do (` ? `./` isn't batch syntax (but bash). Use `.\ ` or omit it completely. The `.` in `in (.)` does nothing (it's just a literal dot). Use a proper wildcard (`*`) If you want just folders, use `for /r /d %%i in (*) do`